# SQL Error Message in the Exception as User Defined Error Message

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table with the following design:

```
tbl_property 
 Fields: property_id(Primary Key),property_name and fpp_id(Foreign Key From another Table tbl_fpp)

tbl_fpp
 Fields: fpp_id(primary_key),fpp_name
```

I have Rows inserted to both tables.

Every time I insert in the `tbl_property` I also get the `fpp_id` from another table.

I wanted to throw an exception to the User in my Visual Basic Application that if I delete a `table_fpp` record, if that record is used/referenced in the `tbl_property` then I will prompt the user a message like. "You cannot delete an FPP because it is used in other record." Else it will delete the record of `table_fpp` if it is not referenced?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8057617/sql-exception-error-547-foreign-key-constraint-violations-while-attempting-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RAISERROR (N' You cannot delete an FPP because it is used in other record.' , -- Message text.
       10, -- Severity,
       1, -- State)
```

You can find more detail here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx